# Memory leak on iOS displaying sequence of base64 images

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, uiimageview, base64

I have lot of base64 images and I want to show them quickly as possible. Problem is, that memory is not released after showing them and also more fps would by great. This is my code for showing base64 image in uiimageview I am mcalling in loop:

```
    NSString message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/jpg;base64,%@",base64string];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:message];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first and important thing you must do is use @autoreleasepool

```
for(....){
@autoreleasepool
{
NSString message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/jpg;base64,%@",base64string];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:message];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
}
```

Sure this will help you in memory release.

Can you also post your code, relevant to above only?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, by the time I found out that leak was caused before displaying the image, it had almost nothing to do with it. `@autoreleasepool` fixed my problem, thanks :)